# Trying to delete data using modal popup, not getting correct id of selected item

Tags: laravel, modal-dialog

I have a table view with many records and I want to have a delete button for each record, which will prompt a modal box for the user to confirm a delete. I am able to have the correct buttons (viewed from the table) to prompt the modal, but the button within the modal, which is the button to confirm a delete doesnt pass the right id. For example, I have 3 records in my table that is shown, with an ID of 1, 2 and 3. But the way I have code my table (will show code below) makes it where the user clicks any of the delete button on the desired record, the modal box pops up, with the "Delete(confirm)" button with an ID of the newest amongst all records. In this situation would be an ID of 3. I want it to pass the correct ID. Meaning if I want to delete record 1 it will pass ID 1 and record 2 and so on

I have tried researching what I did wrongly with my JavaScript but it seems ok and nothing seems to help for now. I have tried putting the whole modal into my table but it still has the same problem...

```
<!-- DataTables Example -->
    <div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="card-header">
        <i class="fas fa-table"></i>
        Advertisements 
        <div></div>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Sort No.</th>
                <th>Updated By</th>
                <th>Expired At</th>
                <th>Updated At</th>
                <th> </th>
                <th> </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              @foreach ($advertisements as $advertisement)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $advertisement->media->title }}</td>
                <td>{{ $advertisement->media->description }}</td>
                <td><img src="{{asset('/storage/uploads/images/').'/'.$advertisement->image}}" height="65" width="100"></td>
                @php
                  if ($advertisement->media->status == 1){
                    $current_status = 'Active';
                  } elseif ($advertisement->media->status == 0){
                    $current_status = 'Inactive';
                  } 
                @endphp
                <td>{{ $current_status }}</td>
                <td>{{ $advertisement->media->sort}}</td>                        
                <td>{{ $advertisement->media->admin->username}}</td>
                <td>{{ $advertisement->expired_at}}</td>
                <td>{{ $advertisement->media->updated_at}}</td>
                <td><a href="/advertisements/{{$advertisement->id}}/edit" class="btn btn-success">Edit</td>
                <td>
                <button class="btn btn-danger delete-record" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="{{$advertisement->id}}" data-url="/advertisements/{{$advertisement->id}}">Delete , {{$advertisement->id}}</button>
                </td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
    </div>
```

Above code is the table view showing my data, and each record will have a delete button next to it.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="deleteForm">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf 
      <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              Are you sure you want to delete this record?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

The code above is my modal box code, with a form that creates a delete request.

The code below is the javascript that is handling the delete and the passing of id and the action:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.delete-record').click(function () {
        var url = $(this).attr('data-url');
        $("#deleteForm").attr("action", url);
    });
});
```

I want it to pass the correct ID. Meaning if I want to delete record 1 it will pass ID 1 and record 2 and so on.

Comment: at this time what id/data/error you are getting?

Comment: I am trying to delete the record with an ID of 1, But the delete button in the modal box keeps pointing towards the newest ID of the table

Answer (score 0):

You try to send your form via POST method, but there is no post data such as advertising id in it.

Can you please show your web.php route file ?

Because if it's POST method here, you should to add hidden input in your form.

Comment: the form action should be "/advertisements/{{$advertisement->id}}" but i put it as a data-url and used that in the JavaScript function, i also added @method('DELETE') below the <form>. and for my route, i just use resource route "Route::resource('advertisements', 'AdvertisementsController');"

Comment: Can you show your destroy method in AdvertisementsController ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

Instead of url you should use route,

```
<button class="btn btn-danger delete-record" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal" data-id="{{$advertisement->id}}" data-action="{{ route('advertisements.destroy', $advertisement->id) }}">Delete , {{$advertisement->id}}</button>
```

In your JS code

```
$("#deleteForm").attr("action", $(this).data('action'));
```

And if you don't put your modal code outside foreach then put it in at end of file

Hope this helps :)